# Constructor not setting up an array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I'm relatively new to Java, currently studying it in a night course. I'm having trouble setting the constructor up correctly so that it moves values entered into an array. I have the below code and it seems that the individual fields are being passed correctly but the array is not populated and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've gone back through my notes, textbooks and checked here. I may just have been staring at it for too long!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

static Scanner InOut = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    //* Declare and initalize variables. Set maximum number of students to 6.
    String surname = "", forename = "", course = "a", newCourse, tmpStu ="";
    int firstMark = 0, secondMark = 0, thirdMark = 0, finalScore = 0,
        option = 0, studentCount = 0, delNum, index = 0;
    final int MAXSTUDENT = 6;
    Student[] myClass = new Student[MAXSTUDENT];


    //* Set class details for the constructor. 

    while (option != 6) {

        //* Call the menu system to be displayed
        option = menu();

        switch (option) {
            //* Checks the value return by the menu for the selected option
            case 1:
                //* Checks that the maximum number of students has not been exceeded. 
                if (studentCount >= MAXSTUDENT) {
                    System.out.println("Maximum number of student entered. \n\n");
                    menu();
                } else {

                    //* Enter in the student details
                    InOut.nextLine();   /* ensures that the buffer is cleared*/

                    System.out.println("Enter student surname: ");
                    surname = InOut.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter student forename: ");
                    forename = InOut.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter 1st mark: ");
                    firstMark = InOut.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter 2nd mark: ");
                    secondMark = InOut.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter 3rd mark: ");
                    thirdMark = InOut.nextInt();
                    finalScore = 0;
                    //* Passes the entered paramaters to add the student details to the object class.
                    //* Increases the student counter by 1. 
                    myClass[studentCount] = new Student(surname, forename, course, firstMark, secondMark, thirdMark, finalScore);
                    System.out.println(myClass[studentCount]);
                    studentCount++;

                }
                break;

            case 2:
                //* Enter in the student number to be deleted. Number is passed for deletion. 
                //* Reduces the number of student counter. 
                System.out.println("Delete which student?");
                delNum = InOut.nextInt();
                deleteStudent(delNum, studentCount);
                studentCount--;
                break;

            case 3:
                //* Allows for the course name to be updated. 
                InOut.nextLine();   /* ensures that the buffer is cleared*/
                System.out.println("Enter new course: ");
                newCourse = InOut.nextLine();
                Student.setCourse(newCourse);
                break;

            case 4:
                //* Display all details stored in the object class. 
                for (index = 0; index < studentCount; index = index + 1){
                Student.displayDetails(index);
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                //* Input the surname of student and this name is passed to 
                //* display the details for this student only. 
                InOut.nextLine();   /* ensures that the buffer is cleared*/
                System.out.println("Enter surname of student you want to search for: ");
                String searchName = InOut.nextLine();
               //* searchStudent(myClass, searchName, index, studentCount);
                break;

            case 6:
                //* Exit program
                System.out.println("End of program");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option");
        }

    }

}

public static int menu() {

    //* Display menu options and returns selection. 
    System.out.println("****Student Menu****");
    System.out.println("1. Add new student details");
    System.out.println("2. Delete Student");
    System.out.println("3. Change Course");
    System.out.println("4. Display All Student Details");
    System.out.println("5. Search Student by Name");
    System.out.println("6. Exit");
    System.out.println("\nInput an option:");
    int option = InOut.nextInt();
    return option;
}



public void addStudent(String surname, String forename, String course, int firstMark, int secondMark, int thirdMark, int finalScore)
    //* Accepts passed paramaters of student details and adds them into the object class. 
{
    System.out.println(surname);
    System.out.println(forename);
    System.out.println(course);
    System.out.println(firstMark);
    System.out.println(secondMark);
    System.out.println(thirdMark);
    System.out.println(finalScore);





}

public static void deleteStudent(int delNum, int studentCount)
    //* Accepts student array number to be deleted and displays details of all
    //* students still stored. 
{
 //*       int asize = myClass.length, index;

 //*       for (index = delNum +1; index < asize; index++)
 //*       {
 //*           myClass[index-1] = myClass[index];
 //*       }
 //*       studentCount --;
}
```

And this is the Student Constructor being called. I'd added in a few display statements to see if I could find where it was going wrong but no luck. I think it may be to do with the constructor being called from the "static void" main method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Student {

private String surname, forename;
private int firstMark, secondMark, thirdMark, finalScore, index;
private int stuCount = 0;
private final int NUMMARK = 3;
private static String course = "French";
Scanner InOut = new Scanner(System.in);



public Student(String surname, String forename, String course, int firstMark, int secondMark, int thirdMark, int finalScore)
{
    System.out.println(surname);
    this.surname = surname;
    this.forename = forename;
    this.course = course;
    this.firstMark = firstMark;
    this.secondMark = secondMark;
    this.thirdMark = thirdMark;
    finalScore = ((firstMark + secondMark + thirdMark)/ NUMMARK);
    this.finalScore = finalScore;

}
public static void setCourse (String newCourse) {
    course = newCourse;

}


private String getDetails()
     //* Builds student details and returns them to be displayed. 
{
    String details = "Student Name: " + surname + ", " + forename +"\n";
    details = details + "Course Name: " + course + "\n";
    details = details + "Student's Marks: " + firstMark + ", " + secondMark + ", " + thirdMark + "\n";
    details = details + "Final Mark: " + finalScore + "\n";
    return details;

}

public static void displayDetails(int index)
    //* Displays all student details that have been entered using the student counter
    //* for the number of times to loop. 
{
  //*      if (myClass[index] != null) {
  //*      System.out.println(myClass[index].getDetails());
  //*      }
}




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
myClass[0] = new Student(surname, forename, course, firstMark, secondMark, thirdMark, finalScore);
studentCount++;
System.out.println(myClass[0]);
```

Is adding each new student on the previous one, you are always setting the first position of the array, it should be like this:

```
myClass[studentCount] = new Student(surname, forename, course, firstMark, secondMark, thirdMark, finalScore);
System.out.println(myClass[studentCount]);//BEFORE the counter increment
studentCount++;
```

Side note:

This code:

```
System.out.println(myClass[studentCount]);
```

Will not print the informations that the student contains. In order to print them you have to override the `toString` method of your `Student` class, returning the string you want to be printed

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk Well, yes, didn't see it, the print should be **before** the increment, thanks

Comment: Apologies I should have said I was trying to see if the array was populated so I set the array to 0 for testing but it was being returned null. I double checked changing to use the counter but I get the same results. Thanks for helping though, its much appreciated!

Comment: @user2512005 Can you post all the relevant code? This code should work, if the array is not populated it means you have other code that is probably erasing it

Comment: @BackSlash I've updated the original post to include the full code. It is still a work in progress so I'm not expecting it all to work but my main concern is the array not populated. Again thanks for your help!

Comment: @BackSlash Thanks for your help! I think I'm getting mixed up for the display like you have above for the overide toString, I'll give that a go now.

Answer (score 1):

your code doesn't have any serious problem. you just have to edit some part of it as follow:

first of all to see the getDeatails() method of your Student class you should declare it as 
protected:
so the new version is as follow

```
protected String getDetails() 

{
    String details = "Student Name: " + surname + ", " + forename + "\n";
    details = details + "Course Name: " + course + "\n";
    details = details + "Student's Marks: " + firstMark + ", " + secondMark + ", " + thirdMark + "\n";
    details = details + "Final Mark: " + finalScore + "\n";
    return details;

}
```

in the first case what you write is ok. you just have to use the appropriate way to retrieve the data from an array. so use the following code:

```
//* Passes the entered paramaters to add the student details to the object class.
//* Increases the student counter by 1. 
myClass[studentCount] = new Student(surname, forename, course,   firstMark, secondMark, thirdMark, finalScore);
for(int i = 0;i<=studentCount;i++){
   System.out.println(myClass[i].getDetails());
   System.out.println("-----------------------");
}
studentCount++;
System.out.println("now the student count are: "+studentCount);
```

the following is for case 4:

```
case 4:
//* Display all details stored in the object class. 
System.out.println("studentcount:"+studentCount);
for (index = 0; index < studentCount; index = index + 1) {
    System.out.println(myClass[index].getDetails());
    System.out.println("---------------------");
}
break;
```

Comment: i guess you know fandamentals of java but in some details you have a problem.